# mod_rewrite force trailing slash except if url had .html extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a problem here..

i have a htaccess like this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
# Rewrite cuiy  
RewriteEngine On
# Ensure all URLs have a trailing slash.
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://store.kiosban.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^produk/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /template/single-product.php?produk=$1&slug=$2 [L] #single produk
RewriteRule ^produk/([^/]*)$ /template/product.php?produk=$1 [L] #archive produk
RewriteRule ^produk/$ http://www.store.kiosban.com/produk/all [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^produk/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /template/product.php?produk=$1&page=$2 [L] #archive produk
RewriteRule ^filter/([^/]*)/ukuran/([^/]*)$ /template/search.php?filter=$1&ukuran=$2 [L] #search by size
RewriteRule ^filter/([^/]*)/ukuran/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /template/search.php?filter=$1&ukuran=$2&page=$3 [L] #search by size
RewriteRule ^filter/([^/]*)/oem/([^/]*)$ /template/search.php?filter=$1&oem=$2 [L] #search by oem
RewriteRule ^filter/([^/]*)/oem/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /template/search.php?filter=$1&oem=$2&page=$3
RewriteRule ^checkout/$ /template/checkout.php
RewriteRule ^checkout/2/ /template/product.php
RewriteRule ^login/$ /template/mlebu.php
RewriteRule ^daftar/$ /template/register.php
```

It works if i insert a url like this

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk
```

It will become like this

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk/
```

BUt the problem is when the url is like this

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk/accesories/accesories.html
```

It will become like this too

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk/accesories/accesories.html/
```

My question is.. how to add the trailing slash when the url is not a .html file...

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk
```

Become

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk/
```

And

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk/accesories/accesories.html
```

Still being

```
http://store.kiosban.com/produk/accesories/accesories.html
```

any suggestion??

Comment: is it OK to add slashes to everything else? Pictures, JS, CSS...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add this to your condition-set:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html$
```

That should prevent the rules from running if the URL ends in `.html`.

Comment: You're very welcome. Please mark the answer as correct so that others may learn from it, and know exactly what the correct way about going it is. :)